# Input argument to bash cgi from html

Tags: html, cgi

I have searched this on google at least 5 times and have not obtained an answer.
I want to have an HTML form with a text input that inputs an argument to my CGI script.

Apologies in advance, I have bad spelling and don't know how to use this site well.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>'
echo '<html><head>'
echo '<title>Template</title>'
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">'
echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'
echo '</head><body>'
echo '<h1>Template</h1>'
echo '<div class="main">'
echo '<pre>'
      ls -la
echo '</pre>'
echo '<form action="index.cgi">'
echo '<input type="text">'
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" name="ls_path">'
echo '</form>'
echo '</div>'
echo '</body></html>'
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clinery,
It is unclear from your question if you are having trouble getting the webserver to run your CGI script, or if you are having trouble processing the input box content in bash.

For the former please make sure your webserver configuration is ok, an example for apache can be found [here](https://linuxconfig.org/simple-cgi-and-apache-examples-on-ubuntu-linux).

For the later please look at the last example "Process input from an HTML form" [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/BashShellCgi.html)

Comment: I have configured the server correctly and that page is showing correctly, what my question is is How do I input the argument to be able to use it in a command. My plan for this is to allow for downloading of site backups which are handled by another script.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was looking in the wrong place